# How to deploy an Eclipse java project into a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project running in Eclipse, and it works fine. Right now, I would like to deploy it to a executable jar, how can I do that? In addition, I have several argument setting in the run configuration window. For instance ,the Program arguments in run configuration window is `-t test –u up`; the VM argument is `–d64`. The main class is `com.myproject.model`.

Answer (score 3):

You should simply be able to go to Export->Java->Jar file in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Simply right-click on the project; go to export - choose location, and then export should be completed.

After that if you are a windows user, you can create it into an application *only* runnable on windows or known as .exe